# how set time of cache forrever in request-cache?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests-cache
requests_cache.install_cache('save_cache',expire_after=3600,filter_fn=check_response)
```

how can i set timeout of cache is forever with expire_after ?
Will expire_after = -1 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `expire_after=-1` means "never expire." There are more details in the docs here: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/expiration.html

Answer (score -1):

oh. i found that if we set expire_after = None, it will ignore expiration
[image]
i found this in requests_cache.core.CachedSession(). Hope it work